# why my vimrc doesn't recognize <BR>

Tags: vim

The following command in vimrc works well for vim in my ubuntu os,

```
:map 11 :tabnext 1<CR>
```

,while in my CentOS system, i entered '11', it returns:
 [image]

, i have to delete `'<CR>'`, and then enter the "`Enter`" key to jump to tab 1;

All the '`<CR>`' in vimrc doesn't work, it seems the vim can't recognize '`<BR>`' as "`Enter`" KEY,  anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace <CR> with <kbd>Ctrl + V</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your CentOS system starts Vim in Vi-compatible mode. To be exact, the `<` flag in `'cpoptions'` seems to be set.

Try launching Vim via `vim -N` or by putting `set cpo-=<` before the mapping definition. If this fixes the issue, you probably want to permanently disable Vi-compatible mode, by putting `set nocompatible` at the top of your `.vimrc`.

Comment: set cpoptions?        cpoptions=aABceFs                                                               set compatible?       nocompatible

Comment: @RoyHu There is a way to force processing special characters in `:map`, no matter whether or not there is `<` flag in 'cpoptions' or whether or not 'compatible' is set: `<special>`: `nnoremap <special> 11 :tabnext 1<CR>`.